# How to: React serialise multidimensional array and unserialise it in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, reactjs, serialization

## -- Edit 2--

*I'm placing this on top since I'm narrowing down on the problem.*

I send this string nested within a bigger array the combines all the attributes for a WP shortcode. The problem lays within the square brackets.

```
{“key”:”post_type”,”value”:[“news”,”agenda"]}
```

My best ques is that I need to escape the square brackets or to search replace on both sides and use a placeholder like `(squareBracketOpen)`.

Or is there another way to serialize/unserialize an array?

The problem lays within the square brackets.

## -- / Edit 2 --

I’m working in React and PHP and I’m tying to add something on top of a Wordpress Plugin. This uses React, which I’m not familiar with at all :)

Right now I have zero knowledge of react, but I’m getting stuff to work bit by bit. There is one thing though I don’t know how to solve. I’ll start with the quesion:

**How do I serialise a multidimensional array in React and unserialise it in PHP?**
If, in any case I miss translate my question, let me state my goal as following:
I have an multidimensional array in React and I want to pass it to PHP and reuse it as an multidimensional array.

This would be the array:

```
Array {
[key] => “post_type”,
[value] => Array {
    [0] => “news”,
    [1] => “agenda”
    }
}
```

As a test in React I do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(post_type));
// expected return {“key”:”post_type”,”value”:[“news”,”agenda"]}
```

--edit-- I've noticed it adds `[ ]` brackets as multidimensional. That's not right, right? -- end edit--

Looks fine to my knowledge, right?

Now in PHP I try to unserialise it with:

```
var_dump( unserialize ($postType ) );
// result: bool(false)
```

So I’m obvious doing something wrong. :)
Would anyone know how to properly serialise the multidimensional array in React and unserialise it in PHP to an array?

Comment: `unserialize()` is used for php-serialized strings, _not_ for JSON strings, use `json_decode()` instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @arkascha, yes indeed. Thanks. json_decode() works good. Now I have to correctly serialize it in React. I think I'm doing something wrong there now.

Comment: That json structure you show is fine, mostly. The square brackets are how arrays are expressed in json. You can prove that by using `json_decode()` on that string in php, it will decode the string correctly, but only if you do one important change: the quote characters in that string you posted are of different type. You can actually see it here in how they are displayed on SO. Only the last one is correct. The issue appears to be the array code initially use, you already introduced that issue there. Change that, use normal quote chars, no something looking similar.

Comment: Not sure how this happened to you, the most likely explanation is that you did not use a code editor for that code, but some stupid word processor or similar. Don't, get a simple code editor or better an IDE for that job.

Comment: @arkascha I'm using PHPstorm. But I've narrowed it down. The problems are the square brackets.

Comment: No, those brackets are perfectly fine in json. I actually tested your string, it can be `json_decode()`'ed just fine in php if I change the quote chars to legal ones. Maybe you could explain _why_ you think those brackets are an issue? I mean how else do you want to serialize an array of values?

Comment: @arkascha, The problem is that I don't send it directly like this. It was embedded as a string into a different attributes array. But I've fixed it as you can see below. I after converting it to string I encoded it for url. To escape my problems. (I'm good at escaping my problems)

Comment: Sure, if you try to transfer a string as a HTTP GET argument then you need to `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`, just as every other string. That has nothing to do with the serialization, though. Usually such payload is transferred using a HTTP POST request for reasons...

Comment: Oh, and... you _still have those invalid quote characters there, even in your update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, finally. What I ended up doing is on the js/react side.

1. Serialize array to string. with JSON.stringify()
2. uri encoded the string. with encodeURIComponent()
3. And on the php side reversed it.

JS/React

```
let post_type_encoded = encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( post_type ) )
```

PHP

```
$postType = json_decode ( urldecode( $postTypeEncoded ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a `json_decode($post_type, true)` for it to be converted into a multi dimensional array.

Note, the second parameter `true` is what converts it to associative array.

So essentially, you'll be doing `JSON.stringify` then `json_decode()` for it work in php

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I think there is a type in your code: last json.decode() should be json_decode(). Right?
It is unserializeing but when I go from array to multidimensional in React it returns NULL. In other words, it works as single layer array, but not as multidimensional.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo :) to answer your question, that might be an error with your json structure. did you check if it is correct?

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem now lays there. I have absolutely no knowledge of React. It involves a lot of stuff I'm not yet familiar with :) I'm looking for stuff to serialize/encode it. But I think I need libraries for this. Think I have to state these in a webpack file. and then install/build it. It's a lot to process for one function :)
Thanks, at least I know the PHP part is fine now.